# Get a enum value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am stuck with a piece code 
There is a object, a field of which returns an enum (getter) the field is set by a function after reading from database. For example

```
Enum fiscalperiond
{
    Num1 = 12;
    Num2 = 13;
}

Class A
{

    Public Fiscalperiod
    {
        NumberOfFiscalPeriod {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now I want to do this how do I do it

```
A a = new A();

int k = a.NumberOfFiscalPeriod;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just cast the enum value to `int`.

```
A a = new A();

int k = (int)a.NumberOfFiscalPeriod;
```

The inverse is valid too, even if there is no enum value defined for that int value, for sample:

```
int i = 13; // int value
EFiscalPeriond f = (EFiscalPeriond) i; // converting int to enum
```

Comment: An interesting note, the cast back will work *even if there is no enum value defined for that int value*. There are some good posts on SO about this.

Comment: Yes @BradleyDotNET I added it to my anwser, thank you.